# Child doesn't connect to parent file from subdirectory

Tags: r, knitr

I want to create a reproducible research file in Rstudio with R and Latex code.
I have parent and two children .Rnw files. My folder organization is like this:

```
+--project_folder
   +--data.csv
   +-- parent_folder
       +-- parent.Rnw
       +-- child1_folder
           +-- child1.Rnw
       +-- child2_folder
           +-- child2.Rnw
```

This is session info:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (Sierra)
```

**parent.Rnw**
In my parent folder I load all packages, import database and do some preprocessing, then I navigate data analysis to two separate children.

```
<blink>
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

<<import-preprocess-data, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE, error=TRUE, warning=TRUE, cache=FALSE>>=
#import data, packages and functions
library(rsubgroup)
library(SDEFSR)
library(xtable)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)

source("./supplement_function/VRE_e.faecium_func.R", chdir = TRUE)
source("./supplement_function/rule-subdataset.R", chdir = TRUE)
source("./supplement_function/confusion-matrix.R", chdir = TRUE)
source("./supplement_function/preprocess-database.R", chdir = TRUE)
source("./supplement_function/result-summary.R", chdir = TRUE)

file_path <- "../data.csv"

database <- read.table(file = file_path, header = TRUE, sep = ";")

#preprocess data
database <- preprocess_data(dataset = database)

#extract data for Enteroccocus faecium
data_E_faecium <- database[database$MICROORGANISM == "ENTEROCOCCUS FAECIUM", ]

<<rsubgroup-child, child="./subgroup_child/rsubgroup-analysis.Rnw", eval=TRUE>>=
@

\end{document}

<\blink>
```

this is how I connect child to parent from subdirectory.

```
<<rsubgroup-to-parent, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
#connect with parent file
set_parent('../report.Rnw')
@
```

When I run whole analysis all is compiled as it should. When I try to compile only child error occurs because preamble from parent file is not included and any object or function from library don't exist in child.

this is how errors looks like at the begining.

[image]

Comment: What is the motivation for knitting the child Rnw directly?

Comment: When you do some changes in analysis you don't have to knit all files to see result in latex, you just knit the child. I am actively working on project and changing code and I don't want to knit everything everytime I do some small change in R code.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest either using knitr's [caching ability](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) -- this can be used so that only the modified chunks are re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks. But I this do not solve the problem why I can't knit only child file. This problem I want to solve, connect child to parent that I can knit child as stand alone file.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible. Aside from caching, another approach I take is to break up the child modules to make them small and modular, and then create light-weight parent documents which import different subsets of the child files, depending on the analysis goals. So for instance, you could extract the key parts needed from parent (library imports, setup, etc.) and copy and paste it into a new document which knits the child. Again, not what you are trying to do, but it may be the best alternative.